# how do i access different key/value pair in parser of YUI datasource's response schema?

Tags: yui

In this example:

```
myDataSource.responseSchema = {

            resultsList: "data",
            fields: [
                {key:"x"},
                {key: "y",
                    parser: function (val) {
                        //here  I want to access value of x......
                        return isNaN(val) ? '(none)' : val;
                    }
                }
            ],
            metaFields: {
                totalRecords: "total",
                startIndex: "page"
            }
        };
```

How can I access the value of key "`y`" in parser of key "`x`"?

Answer (score 0):

During the parse phase, you don't have access to the result set that's being built.  It looks like you're conflating parsing with UI formatting, though.  Try moving that parser logic to the column formatter.  In column formatters, you can access all data for the current record via o.record.getData('y').  There's an example of this in the "Working with Row Data" section of the DataTable user guide: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/#data

Comment: My daily vote limit is reached, so no luck for you today, Luke. But maybe I'll remember this tomorrow :)